# How to use projection in Dart mongo db driver

Tags: mongodb, dart

I have two records in persons collection with many fields. I just want to fetch firstName and lastName fields.

The code below returns only _id fields but does not get the firstName and lastName fields:

```
var v1 = await db.collection('persons').modernFind(
    selector: SelectorBuilder(),
    projection: {'firstName': 1, 'LastName': 1}).toList();
```

Output is as follows:

```
[{_id: ObjectId("62addc05291b7ff654dc787a")}, {_id: 
 ObjectId("62ae1f8cc9042cd46f9d49dd")}]
```

Removing selector: does not change the result.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var v1 = await 
db.collection('persons').find(where.list(['firstName','lastName']);
```